# restrict error pages in default cq5 search

Tags: java, javascript, aem

I am using the CQ5 out-of-the-box search component.  My problem is that the error pages are getting displayed in the search results.

May I know how I can restrict error pages from getting displayed in the search.
Do we need to add a new property for the page so that it can be restricted by QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unable to separate content that you do not wish to be index from that which you do, the search indexer can be configured to ignore certain content or attributes within specified content.  This is described in some detail on the ["How to modify the search engine configurations in CQ5](http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/SearchIndexingConfig.html) page on the [Adobe CQ Help](http://www.adobe.com/go/learn_cq_destination_en) site.

Essentially, attributes can be ignored by the indexer by adding them to the indexing_config.xml file like so:

```
<index-rule nodeType="nt:base">
  <!-- ... existing ignored properties -->
  <property nodeScopeIndex="false">mySecretProperty</property>
</index-rule>
```

The following should exclude pages of a nodes with a specific resourceType and their descendents.

```
<index-rule nodeType="nt:base" condition="@sling:resourceType='app/components/errorPage'" />
<index-rule nodeType="nt:base" condition="ancestor::*/@excludefromindex='app/components/errorPage'" />
```

The Jackrabbit [Indexing Configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/IndexingConfiguration) page has some more details on the syntax of this file.

Content will not automatically be re-indexed, details of how to trigger a reindex can be found [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/crx/kb/DisableIndexingPartOfContent.html).

Comment: Ya, I have added the below lines                                                                         <index-rule nodeType="nt:base" condition="@excludefromindex='true'" />
<index-rule nodeType="nt:base" condition="ancestor::*/@excludefromindex='true'" />
and added that property excludefromindex directly in the jcr:content of the error page I tried to access, now it is shown in search results. But you told the more standard way, like creating mixin type, I have done that,then I opened content explorer and May I know how to add this mixin property to the error page I want to restrict

Comment: Hi Diffa,I followed your way of mapping the property to the cq:page from content explorer, it worked like a charm,Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Diffa,I tried to do this from code side,             addPredicate(new Predicate("mytype", "type").set("group.4_group.1_property", "jcr:content/cq:template"));so that I will exclude all the pages from search by specifying the template for which those pages are mapped, but this method addPredicate() is not present in the default search api, it is present in simplesearchimpl which is present in the package com.day.cq.search.impl.SimpleSearchImpl,however If i try to use that package, it is throwing error that package does not exist.

Comment: Hi,I already asked, please search with keyword simplesearchimpl        Thanks,                                                                          Balaji.

Answer (score 1):

In the dialog box where you configure your search results component instance (which would be on your search results page), look for a field called "Path to search in."  This maps to a property in the CRX called `searchIn`.  Set this property to a subtree of your content that excludes your error page(s).  For instance, if you set up your content tree to be

```
/content
    /searchable-content
        home-page
        ...
    /error-pages
        404
        401
        ...
```

In this case, you would set your `searchIn` to be `/content/searchable-content`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, will try this and let you know

Comment: Hi,You are correct, but my problem is that these error pages are under the same directory where the other pages are also there, so that is why I need to somehow restrict these pages

Comment: Hi by adding the two lines                                       <index-rule nodeType="nt:base" condition="@excludefromindex='true'" />
<index-rule nodeType="nt:base" condition="ancestor::*/@excludefromindex='true'" /> in indexing_config.xml file and adding that property excludefromindex in the jcrcontent of the page manually, Im able to restrict the page, now trying how to add that from configuration side as suggested by Diffa

Comment: Thank you very much David, it is working fine after adding the mixin property(created in nodetype administrator)  to the page(from content explorer) that I want to restrict

Comment: Hi David,I tried to do this from code side,             addPredicate(new Predicate("mytype", "type").set("group.4_group.1_property", "jcr:content/cq:template"));so that I will exclude all the pages from search by specifying the template for which those pages are mapped, but this method addPredicate() is not present in the default search api, it is present in simplesearchimpl which is present in the package com.day.cq.search.impl.SimpleSearchImpl,however If i try to use that package, it is throwing error that package does not exist.  thanks Balaji